# Regex cisco interface parent and child

Tags: regex, ansible

Below content:

```
interface Vlan10
  ip address 10.17.8.17/30
  ip ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 3 xsdssdsdjhsd
  ip router ospf 14 area 0.0.0.0
  no shutdown
interface Vlan140
  vrf member Automation
  ip address 10.75.54.14/30
  ip router eigrp 1
  no shutdown
interface Vlan150
  vrf member Automation
  ip address 10.15.24.29/30
  ip router eigrp 1
  no shutdown
interface Vlan24
  ip address 10.17.54.50/30
  ip router eigrp 10
  no shutdown
interface Vlan101
  ip address 10.11.10.2/24
  ip ospf cost 1000
  ip router ospf 14 area 0.0.0.1
  no shutdown
interface Vlan1221
  ip address 10.41.12.4/30
  ip ospf cost 10
  ip router ospf 1 area 0.0.0.0
  no shutdown
interface Vlan122
  ip address 10.14.2.53/30
  ip ospf cost 9
  ip router ospf 1 area 0.0.0.0
  no shutdown
interface Vlan1258
  vrf member Automation
  ip address 10.11.1.23/30
  ip router eigrp 1
  no shutdown
interface port-channel16
  switchport
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,15,121
```

Need help to capture the `ip router eigrp` and `ip address` which are the child and interface name(vlan, ethernet) etc... at end repeat this process for all interfaces that contains all three.

Expected goups are interface name, ip address, eigrp number per inteface and repeat the same for all interfaces.

Just to add only need to grab interfaces that has eigrp.

Tried this but didn't work -> ^interface (\S+)?(?:\s+)?(?:(ip address )(\S+))?(?:(?:ip router eigrp)(\S+))

Comment: Tried this with no luck **interface (\S+)?(?:\s+)?(?:(ip address )(\S+))?(?:(?:ip router eigrp)(\S+))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to filter based on router eigrp or ospf with lookbehind and then loop through using ansible.

^interface (\S+)(?:\n\s{2}.*)*(?<=eigrp)